# How to use an NSInteger in a c-style class declaration

Tags: c++, cocoa, objective-c++

I have a c-style class declaration:

```
#pragma once

class CSound
{
private:
   NSInteger bufferID;
public: 
    CSound(const char* fileName);
    ~CSound();
    static void init();
    void play();
};
```

The compiler says **NSInteger does not name a type**.

If I put the "NSInteger bufferID;" in the .mm file (not in the .h) it works. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

As I still have no solution, I did a quick dirty-ugly-fix:

in .h file, in the class definition

```
void* pBufferID;
```

and in the .mm file

```
// constructor
pBufferID = new NSUInteger;

// destructor
delete (NSUInteger*)pBufferID;

// everywhere I use it
*((NSUInteger*)pBufferID)
```

Comment: `int`? Maybe I misunderstood. :p

Comment: C doesn't know classes. This is c++. Did you import the Foundation header?

Comment: I cannot import them without getting tons of errors like "NSObjCRuntime.h : Expected unqualified-id before '@' token. I still don't understand why I cannot use it in the .h file.

Comment: PS I know that C doesn't know classes... but the word c++-style looks not good :)

Answer (score 2):

You're not including the header that defines `NSInteger` from your own header file (probably Foundation.h). Presumably you *are* doing so in your `.mm` file.  Just move that `#import` or `#include` directive into your header.

Comment: No I don't import anything except my .h file. If I add foundation.h in my .h, I get tons of errors in files of the frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the:

`#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>` (iOS)
 or

`#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>` (Mac OS)

..imported at the top of your .h file?

And are you sure you have all the frameworks linked to your project?

```
foundation.framework
appKit.framework
UIKit.framework
```

Comment: The NSInteger DO work in the .mm file. So yes, I have all this stuff linked.